# AngularJS undefined is not a function error in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error with below code:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.AppCtrl.$scope.refresh
```

my partial front end that used ng-repeat

```
<ion-content>
        <div class="card list" data-ng-repeat="p in posts">
        <div class="item item-avatar-left">
            <img data-ng-src="{{p.author.avatar_URL}}">
            <h2>{{p.author.nice_name}}</h2>
            <p><a href="{{p.author.URL}}"></a>{{p.author.URL}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-body">
        <h1>{{p.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{p.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

My app.js file

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ionic']);

App.service("FreshlyPressed", ["$http","$log",FreshlyPressed]);
App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "FreshlyPressed", "$log", AppCtrl]);

function AppCtrl($scope, $log, FreshlyPressed){
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope); 
  }
}

function FreshlyPressed($http, $log){
    this.getBlogs = function($scope){
        $http.jsonp("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
        .success(function(result){
            $scope.posts = result.posts;
        });
    }
}
```

I pass the $scope and expect it to work, but I got an undienfed error at line `FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your dependency injection order is incorrect

```
App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "FreshlyPressed", "$log", AppCtrl]);
```

change to

```
App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$log","FreshlyPressed", AppCtrl]);
```

Comment: does the order matter?

Comment: Yes it does matter. :) As per the arguments passed FreshlyPressed is referring to $log, however $log doesn't have any method called getBlogs.